# Error in `purrr::map()` Caused by error in `rename()`:

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a function that returns a list of eventids

```
[1] "314cdd9cecb9b66219c944996f0249b2" "ab26545fc28c693c52329db2a68a06a9" 
"818b7fece8a6f82cecf0b4ef38f903d3"
 [4] "9427475e5b454a44a4d9cc365d72e416" "3ee7569ac3f38bd5d62ca03b13ee1344" 
"35c8c545c966fd2ad738dcccd02a6d8f"
 [7] "f2aa3876acabca48a66ea6eae3d9f1b9" "63308e00869e2009bc6597edbdaf0c99" 
"96e9ac4414cf1fb0ef4164d710c420c8"
[10] "e6b22267452d3dd4d99fa62ff71f7fcc" "8d78600b0a7ab6a7f15c5f935cbace68" 
"80d27fa88ccd30a960caacce5dfac049"
[13] "c95982844161e998ab02c1eab506902d"
```

I then have a function that executes using the eventids in the above list

```
purrr::map(event_ids, ~my_func(sport = "basketball_nba", eventId = .x))
```

Under normal circumstances it will return something similar to the following

```
my_func('basketball_nba', '314cdd9cecb9b66219c944996f0249b2')
# A tibble: 475 × 13
id                               sport_key  sport…¹ comme…² home_…³ away_…⁴ bookm…⁵ title key   
last_…⁶ name  price point
<chr>                            <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr> 
<chr> <chr>   <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 314cdd9cecb9b66219c944996f0249b2 basketbal… NBA     2023-0… Charlo… Miami … draftk… Draf… 
alte… 2023-0… Char…  -475  15.5
```

However, if one of the eventids doesn't contain information the following error is thrown

```
> nba_alt_lines <- purrr::map(event_ids, ~my_func(sport = "basketball_nba", eventId = .x))
Error in `purrr::map()`:
ℹ In index: 7.
Caused by error in `rename()`:
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `key` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/purrr_error_indexed>
Error in `purrr::map()`:
ℹ In index: 7.
Caused by error in `rename()`:
! Can't rename columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `key` doesn't exist.
---
Backtrace:
1. purrr::map(event_ids, ~my_func(sport = "basketball_nba", eventId = .x))
12. dplyr:::rename.data.frame(., bookmaker_key = "key")
```

My question is there a way to programatically skip an eventid if it doesn't have any information and process the other eventids?

Comment: Based on an edit you added to answer - https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33923830 - I tried to make it bit easier to follow; parenthesis placement can get bit tricky there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your function with `safely()`, execution can then continue and it returns `result` and `error` objects. Punctuation can get bit tricky, `safely()` is a wrapper around function, not function call. Meaning one must be careful when passing parameters, so in your case, you should use

```
map(eventids, ~ safely(nba_alt_lines)(sport = "basketball_nba", eventId = .x))
```

instead of

```
map(eventids, ~ safely(nba_alt_lines(sport = "basketball_nba", eventId = .x)))
```

Edited and moved the wrapping part out of `map()` expression for better readability. Resulting list is also passed through `transpose()`, it turns list-of-lists "inside-out" (a list of results & errors vs results list & errors list)

```r
library(purrr)

ids <- c("A","B-NOK","C")

# execute error action if id includes "NOK"
my_func <- function(id){
  if (grepl("NOK", id)) stop("Fail")
  tibble::tibble_row(req_id = id, result = "OK")
}

# wrap a function with safely()
# note that it's the function and not function call that gets wrapped
safe_my_func <- safely(my_func)

results_s <- map(ids, ~ safe_my_func(.x)) |> 
  transpose()

# results
results_s$result
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   req_id result
#>   <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 A      OK    
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   req_id result
#>   <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 C      OK

# errors
results_s$error
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> <simpleError in .f(...): Fail>
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL

# results collected to a single tibble
list_rbind(results_s$result, names_to = "list_id")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   list_id req_id result
#>     <int> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1       1 A      OK    
#> 2       3 C      OK
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your help @margusl!  The commands work flawlessly and create a lovely tibble full of alternate lines!